# asp.net c# converting data in a dataset into body of an email?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the best way to go from a dataset to the body of an email?

I have a .net console app to send email notification based on results of a stored proc and wanted to know how best to go from SQL data to Email body?

html body with colors and fonts would be best but plain text is also fine.

thanks.

Comment: Best for what? Maintainability? Speed? Readability? Reliability? Throughput? Something else?

Comment: How would you like to apply color and fonts on a plain text you stored on  a sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static string getHTML(DataTable dt) {
        StringBuilder myBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        myBuilder.Append("<table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' ");
        myBuilder.Append("style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;'>");

        myBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
        foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
        {
            myBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
            myBuilder.Append(myColumn.ColumnName);
            myBuilder.Append("</td>");
        }
        myBuilder.Append("</tr>");

        foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            myBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
            foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
            {
                myBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
                myBuilder.Append(myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                myBuilder.Append("</td>");
            }
            myBuilder.Append("</tr>");
        }
        myBuilder.Append("</table>");

        return myBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I have a general doubt, whether string builder is the only option to create html dynamically in c#?

Answer (score 1):

How's that:

1. Reference System.Web (add using System.Web.UI.WebControls;)
2. Instantiate DataGrid or GridView or whatever output you like
3. Bind DataTable
4. Render to string - use something like

   > ```
   > var buffer = new StringBuilder(); 
   > var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(buffer))) 
   > datagrid.RenderControl(tw); 
   > var emailbodyHtmlPart = buffer.ToString();
   > ```
5. Do this for every DataTable in DataSet
6. Add results to html body of email

This is, of course, not tested, but should work in principle.