# How to Send TableAdapter results via email

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a Simple VB Application that contacts a dataset, and spits out the info to a reportviewer on load.  I want to take the tableadapter info (the query that is stored) and send that info as the body of an email... Right now in the load I have:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                Me.Paid_Out_TbTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.Paid_Out_Tb)



        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub
```

How would I have the program send that information in an email?

I assume it would be something along the lines of removing the Me.reportviewer1 and using the System.Net.Mail?  But How would I assign the Body as the tableadapter?

I included C# because I can easily switch to C# if needed...

Thanks.

Comment: explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379532/asp-net-c-sharp-converting-data-in-a-dataset-into-body-of-an-email

Comment: Where is it Sending the email?  I do not see anything that calls an email function...

Comment: Like o3Usr said the answer to what you would like to do is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379532/asp-net-c-sharp-converting-data-in-a-dataset-into-body-of-an-email][1] But you should really provide a method for the user to see the data by clicking a link also. For example based on a querystring or other information you could then link them to a page with the data. This way if their email doesnt support html or if something happens when the email is being sent there is another method of viewing the data.