# How to send Gridview by eMail

Tags: c#, html, gridview

I have created GridView in C#.Net(Desktop Application). Now I want to send this Gridview by Mail to user.

Please tell me how Can I achieve this (either by Exporting Grid to HTML or anything else??).

I have tried below   in HTML but getting lots of formatting issue.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = data1.ToString();
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = data2.ToString();

mailBody.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>",data1.ToString() );
mailBody.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", data2.ToString());
```

Comment: Here you have similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379532/asp-net-c-sharp-converting-data-in-a-dataset-into-body-of-an-email

Comment: Thanks for Info..I am trying that suggestions..

Comment: Hey Javiere..Thanks a lot...above link gave me resolution...I posted answer...

Answer (score 0):

Did it this way...
I had Gridview which was generated programatically without datasource so was facing issue...

Below trick worked :) :)

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }

      //  StringBuilder myBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        myBuilder.Append("<table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' ");
        myBuilder.Append("style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;'>");

        myBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
        foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
        {
            myBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
            myBuilder.Append(myColumn.ColumnName);
            myBuilder.Append("</td>");
        }
        myBuilder.Append("</tr>");

        foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            myBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
            foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
            {
                myBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
                myBuilder.Append(myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                myBuilder.Append("</td>");
            }
            myBuilder.Append("</tr>");
        }
        myBuilder.Append("</table>");
    }
```